# Mac Minecraft Client Timesout connecting to Windows Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Mac Air OS Sierra 10.12.6 and my buddy is running Windows 10. He has set up a Minecraft Server on his computer and we are trying to play like we are on LAN. Minecraft is 1.16.1

We are on different networks, his firewalls are off on the router and host computer. Also port forwarding is correct.

I have to connect using his public IP and the router should do the rest. But the connection to server always throws a io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException.

Does anyone else know how to fix this or troubleshoot or has any ideas as to what may be the issue here?